# Permission denied on python3 command

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, python-venv, pyvenv

I am new to running the python backend api and I was encountering permission denied on this command:
[image]

Comment: Can you try running it with sudo ? `sudo python3 -m venv venv`.

Comment: I also tried but I got this error: `bash: sudo: command not found`

btw I was using windows machine

Comment: What is venv ? Does this contains the python code ?

Comment: I think it is a virtual environment generated by `python3 -m venv venv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a windows specific issue. Windows store recently added Python 3.7 and it is conflicting with your installed version of python. What you can do is the following:

1. Go to windows search and type "manage app execution aliases" and go
   to that setting.
2. Disable the following two options. [image]
3. Make sure your installed version of python is in the environment variable.
4. Go to your desired directory and enter the command "python -m venv venv" and this time it will create a virtual environment.

Comment: You're Welcome @Kev